# Unable to navigate to the files/folders pane in Nautilus with keyboard

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, nautilus

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

For my work efficiency I prefer using keyboard instead of mouse/touchpad, whenever possible.

I can open nautilus using the Files icon (using the launcher shortcut, in my case it's the third icon from the top so I use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>).

But then I'm not able to navigate to the pane listing the files/folders with keyboard.

The <kbd>Tab</kbd> key can be used to cycle over the controls in Nautilus window but it never reaches the actual file pane where the directories are.

How do I navigate using keyboard only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **can** reproduce your issue with Nautilus 3.26.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 when using the *Ambiance* gtk3 theme which is the default in Ubuntu 18.04. Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> any number of times *does not apparently* get me to the pane listing files and folders.

But, if you switch to the *High Contrast* gtk3 theme, which though not aesthetic, makes it very clear when you've tabbed to the point that the file/folder pane is active. (To change gtk themes you'll need to install `gnome-tweaks` from the repos.)

In the following animation, I've used the *materia-gtk-theme* from the repos to show that just tabbing is enough to get to the pane containing the list of files/folders. (I converted images to grayscale so that the animated gif falls below the site's size limit of 2MB.)

First, repeatedly pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> works down the left pane, aka Places, and then enters the pane with the file/folders list. Further tabbing moves to the area above the file list pane.

[image: Tabbing through Nautilus]

In any case, if you like using the keyboard primarily, why not try something like *ranger* or *nnn*? There are many nice YouTube videos on *ranger* and other keyboard-driven file managers.

Answer (score 0):

when you open nautilus with Super+3..
click the right arrow key 2 times..

[image]